# htaccess replace an image (external server) with another internal image if it does'nt exist

Tags: jquery, .htaccess

On my site I store my images on a folder on a remote server, and I integrate this on my site via sshfs.

Before, when images were stored on my site I used a .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -F
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI} \. (Gif | jpg | jpeg | png) $
RewriteRule. * Image.png [L]
```

However this no longer works ...

I saw another method

```
$ ("img"). on ("error", function () {
     $ (this) .attr ("src", "image.png");
});
```

But that doesn't work either .. (and no error message)

Do you have any idea how I could handle this?

For information I recall that I am calling images from an external server.
If possible I prefer to avoid going through the ID attribute because the script must be automatic on all images on the site

Thanks in advance !

Comment: couldn´t u mount the external drive somewhere in the document-root of your site? If so you´d just have to rewrite the path

Comment: You have a lot of spacing "errors" in your code samples (maybe in an attempt to fix formatting?). The jQuery (or JS) solution "should" work. However, this is going to be relatively slow compared to your previous `.htaccess` method.

Comment: john Smith, the edit is on the root of the website;)

MrWhite I have very few images which may be in error. But I have to deal with them. I have no errors with the jquery code, so indeed it is supposed to work but it doesn't ...
For the .htaccess is it possible to modify it so that it can work?

Comment: To me it actually is unclear how that rewriting rule should actually work. Apart from the multiple obvious syntax errors in those lines it will replace each and every image by a single, static image. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Please be more specific in your description here: what does "no longer works" actually mean? What happens if you request such an image? What response do you actually get from your server and what do you see in your http server's log files?

Comment: arkascha Yes indeed, the goal is that if the images on the page does'nt exist, they should be replaced with a default image.

Comment: Why was this using the `-F` flag before already, what made it necessary to check for the existence via a sub-request? What about how you are referring to those images has changed now? How _exactly_ did you integrate the sshfs mount?

Comment: `$ ("img").on("error"` is unlikely to work reliably. You would need to execute this _after_ the image elements already exist in the DOM - but by that time, the error will likely already have happened, "in the past" (the 404 response is probably very "lightweight", and goes over the wire in little to no time.) If anything, you would have to use inline event handlers, to make this work in a reliable fashion. `<img onerror="this.src='image.png'" src="ima404.png'>`

Comment: or you try this syntax: `$(document).on("error", "img",  function(){` ...